# Increase score in quiz using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I am currently working on an online quiz using JavaScript, HTML and CSS. I am pretty happy with it this far but am having an issue trying to add a user score to the game. I am lookig for the score to increase put 5 points for every question the user gets a correct answer for. I have tried a few different ways of doing it but seem to keep coming up with the same issue, the score is not increasing. This is my latest attempt at it, can anyone give me a bit of advice please?

````
const scorePanelElement = document.getElementById('score-panel');
const userScoreElement = document.getElementById('user-score');
const scoreCounterElemet = document.getElementById('score-counter');
const questionCounterElement = document.getElementById('question-counter');

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", startButton)

let shuffledQuestions, currentQuestionIndex;
let questionCounter = 1;
let scoreCounter = 5;
let score = 5;
let selectedAnswer;
let maxQuestions = 10;

startButton.addEventListener("click", startGame)
nextButtonElement.addEventListener('click', () => {
    currentQuestionIndex++
    nextQuestion()
    userScore()
  })


console.log(questions)


function startGame() {
    console.log('StartGame');
    startButton.classList.add('hidden');
    shuffledQuestions = questions.sort(() => Math.random() - .5);
    currentQuestionIndex = 0;
    questionPanelElement.classList.remove('hidden');
    questionCounter = 0;
    scoreCounter = 0;
    callQuestions();
}

function checkAnswer(e) {
    selectedAnswer = e.target
    const correct = selectedAnswer.dataset.correct;
    Array.from(answerButtonsElement.children).forEach(button => {
        answerChoice(button, button.dataset.correct);
    })
    if (shuffledQuestions.length > currentQuestionIndex + 1) {
        callQuestions;
    } else {
        nextButtonElement.classList.add('hidden');
        questionPanelElement.classList.add('hidden');
        usernameElement.classList.remove('hidden');
    }
    answerChoice; 
}

 
function userScore() {
    if (selectedAnswer === 'correct') {
        scoreCounter++;
        scoreCounterElemet.innerText = + score;
    }
    console.log('Increase Score')
}```
````

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? It could help to check for undefined variables - what does `selectedAnswer` contain in case `userScore()` is called?

Comment: Unfortunetely you code snippet is not consisten so it's hard to investigate your problem. At first glance it seems that `selectedAnswer` in the `checkAnswer` function assigned with html element  from e.target but in the `userScore` function you tries to compare `selectAnswer` with a string value. Maybe you missed the correct property navigation, e.g. selectedAnswer.dataset.correct?

Comment: Martiless; is this still unresolved? Did my answer help? :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here might be

```
function userScore() {
    if (selectedAnswer === 'correct') {
        // increases scoreCounter by one
        scoreCounter++;

        // sets the element text into something that doesn't really make sense
        scoreCounterElemet.innerText = + score;
    }
    console.log('Increase Score')
}
```

Instead, try something like this

```
function userScore() {
    if (selectedAnswer === 'correct') {
        scoreCounter = scoreCounter + 5; // increases scoreCounter by 5

        // sets the element text to the current score
        scoreCounterElemet.innerText = scoreCounter; 
    }
    console.log('Increase Score')
}
```